# Doctrine2: Generate entities based on entity class

Tags: php, mysql, doctrine-orm, symfony

I would like to generate many the same tables with different name. Is it possible to create one entity class with mapping like(http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/doctrine.html#add-mapping-information) and than run a command with parameter name to create the table into database? I already done one solution, but it is not based on entity class.

in constructor:

```
public function __construct()
{
    $this->schema = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Schema();
    $this->config = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Configuration();
    $this->connection = DriverManager::getConnection($this->connectionParams, $this->config);
    $this->queryBuilder = $this->connection->createQueryBuilder();
    $this->myPlatform = new MySqlPlatform();
    $this->comparator = new \Doctrine\DBAL\Schema\Comparator();
}
```

Than the create function:

```
public function setTable($name)
{
$myTable = $this->schema->createTable($name);
$myTable->addColumn("id", "integer", array("unsigned" => true));
$myTable->addColumn("name", "string", array("length" => 32));
$myTable->setPrimaryKey(array("id"));
$myTable->addUniqueIndex(array("name"));

$queries = $this->schema->toSql($this->myPlatform);
$sm = $this->connection->getSchemaManager();
$fromSchema = $sm->createSchema();
$toSchema = $this->schema;

$schemaDiff = $this->comparator->compare($fromSchema, $toSchema);
$queries = $schemaDiff->toSql($this->myPlatform);
$sql = $schemaDiff->toSaveSql($this->myPlatform);
foreach ($sql as $sentence) {
        $this->connection->exec($sentence);
    }
}
```

Is there any other solution based on one class with mapping and a command with parameter $table_name to create the same table with different name? I am using Symfony 3 with Doctrine 2.

Comment: Anyone? Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Entity class is an object that should be connected with a table and correspond to it. I think that a better way would be to make one EntityAbstractClass which looks exactly like yours, but without the @ORM\Table() annotation, and then create multiple Entities that extends your EntityAbstractClass.

Abstract Class:

```
abstract class EntityAbstractClass() {
    // your fields here
}

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="first_table")
**/
class FirstEntityClass extends EntityAbstractClass {

}

/**
* @ORM\Table(name="second_table")
**/
class SecondEntityClass extends EntityAbstractClass {

}
```

and so on. You can also manage it programmatically by saving short files, and then run schema update.

Alternatively instead of Abstract Class you can use Traits:

```
trait MyEntityTrait {
    // your fields here like:
    /** @ORM\Column() **/
    private $name;
}
```

and in every new entity class:

```
/**
* @ORM\Table(name="first_table")
**/
class FirstEntityClass {
    use MyEntityTrait;
}
```

...

Comment: Good answer, I was thinking about that too, but the problem is that you don't know the number of entities in advance.

Comment: You can use some script to generate Entity files depending on what you need there.